# 3D ribbon using CSS and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a 3D ribbon using CSS and JavaScript.

Main features needed are:

1. Ribbon should use sticky scroll method. i.e. moves from bottom to top on page scroll and then get fixed at the top.
2. 3D effect in ribbon, it changes it's perspective on scroll

I have created the effect, here's the demo page: http://staging.xhtml-lab.com/ribbon/

You can check the code by using view source, JS is at the bottom of page.

But it have some bugs, which i am not being able to fix and looking for help:

1. Corner (triangles) are not moving properly on scroll
2. It works fine if i scroll slowly, but everything is messed up on scrolling fast
3. If i scroll down and refresh the page, ribbon is moved down and calculations are messed up.

I am looking for help to fix these issues.

Following is the JS code:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            var docHeight = $(window).height();
            var ribbonOffsetTop = 200;
            var ribbonOffsetBottom = 50;
            var initialPosition = parseInt($('#ribbon').css('top'));
            var lastScrollTop = 0;

            var ribbonHeight = 74;
            var availableScroll = docHeight-ribbonOffsetTop-ribbonOffsetBottom;
            var step = availableScroll/34;
            var remainingScroll = availableScroll-step;
            var stepsMoved = 0;

            console.log(availableScroll);

            $(window).scroll(function() {
                var st = $(this).scrollTop();

                if (st > lastScrollTop){
                    // downscroll code - Ribbon moving up
                    if (parseInt($('#ribbon').css('top')) > ribbonOffsetTop) {
                        $('#ribbon').css('top', initialPosition - parseInt(st));

                        var scrollingPosition = docHeight-st-ribbonOffsetTop-ribbonOffsetBottom;
                        if(remainingScroll > scrollingPosition) {
                            remainingScroll -= step;

                            $('.ribbon-front').css("top", $('.ribbon-front').position().top - 1);

                            if(stepsMoved < 17) {
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerleft').css("border-width", (17 - stepsMoved)+"px 26px 0 0");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerright, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("border-width", (17 - stepsMoved)+"px 0 0 26px");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-outerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("top", stepsMoved-34);
                            } else {
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-innerright').css("top", stepsMoved -17);
                                $('.ribbon-edge-outerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("top", "23px");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerleft').css("border-width", "0px 26px "+(stepsMoved - 17)+"px 0");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerright, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("border-width", "0px 0 "+(stepsMoved - 17)+"px 26px");
                            }
                            stepsMoved ++;
                        }
                    }
                } else if (st < lastScrollTop ) {
                    // upscroll code - Ribbon moving down
                    if (parseInt($(this).scrollTop()) <= docHeight-ribbonOffsetTop-ribbonOffsetBottom) {
                        $('#ribbon').css('top', (docHeight-parseInt(st))-ribbonHeight);

                        var scrollingPosition = docHeight-st-ribbonOffsetTop-ribbonOffsetBottom;

                        if(remainingScroll < scrollingPosition) {
                            remainingScroll += step;

                            $('.ribbon-front').css("top", $('.ribbon-front').position().top + 1);

                            if(stepsMoved > 17) {
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerleft').css("border-width", "0px 26px "+(stepsMoved - 17)+"px 0");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerright, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("border-width", "0px 0 "+(stepsMoved - 17)+"px 26px");
                            } else {
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-innerright').css("top", stepsMoved -17);
                                $('.ribbon-edge-outerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("top", "23px");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerleft').css("border-width", (17 - stepsMoved)+"px 26px 0 0");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-innerright, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("border-width", (17 - stepsMoved)+"px 0 0 26px");
                                $('.ribbon-edge-outerleft, .ribbon-edge-outerright').css("top", stepsMoved-34);
                            }
                            stepsMoved --;
                        }
                    }
                }
                lastScrollTop = st;
            });

        });
```

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/notes/css3-ribbon-menu/